# Show two different sized featured images on homepage

Tags: homepage, images

I would like to have **two different sized featured images** on my homepage.  I currently have all featured images set to 280x200.  I would like to have SOME posts on the home page display a larger 620x200 image and others the 280x200.  I'm not sure how to accomplish this.  I realize I can specify a custom image size in my functions file like `add_image_size( 'large-image', 620, 200, true );`.  However, I'm not sure how to get my homepage to know which image to display?

I have no idea if this is an optimal approach or not but I was thinking of making a custom field called 'large-featured' and having the homepage check to see if `large-featured` custom field value is set to true.  Upon true use `large-image` custom size and upon no custom field value set use wordpress default featured size.

I'm not good at php coding so a little help here would be awesome.  I'm pretty good and figuring things out with a little direction.  Thanks for your assistance.  Much appreciated.

My site in question is: http://www.fighterstyle.com

Answer (score 1):

With `get_post_thumbnail()` you have the ability to insert a featured image in your theme.
`the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr );` holds to parameter 1. The size of your image and the ID.

If you would like to have 2 image sizes of featured images on your home page you could do it like this:

```
if(is_front_page(){  // only on frontpage
 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
  the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(320,320));
 } 

}else if(is_page()){
  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(120,120));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using a custom field sounds good to me. You can then access this data using the `get_post_meta` function as [described in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), and use that to pass the values of the size.

As to what values to pass, instead of passing hard coded sizes, it's better if you define the desired sizes in the `Settings -> media` screen, and then you can use the WP keywords thumbnail, medium, large or full when calling the `get_the_post_thumbnail` function

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you have to add new size if it not implement yet:

```
add_image_size( 'feature_name', 320, 200, true/false );
```

The media uploader will create the images in the currect size from now.

If you have old images it will not regenerate the images to the new size, use `AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild` plugin.

Now you can call:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'feature_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to get the url of the thumbnail image instead of the thumbnail image which is already resized when you set it as featured image...

```
<?php
// check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
$image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()) );
//$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID())); this gets the thumbnail image which is resized.
}?>
<img src="<?php echo $image;?>"/>
```

Comment: Why do this instead of using size parameters as suggested in other answers? How do you avoid distorting the image when you force those dimensions?

Comment: the $image will store the url of your orignal image not distorted, if you want to use the orignal image without distortion just use the <img src="<?php echo $image;?>".

Comment: But _as written_ you are forcing the image to a height and width which is likely to lead to distortion. Of course, if you _do something different_, that won't happen but that doesn't explain _this_ answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom field - large_featured. If the value = 1 the large standard size will be displayed. Else - medium.

```
$large_featured = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'large_featured', true );
if(!empty($large_featured) && $large_featured == '1') {
    the_post_thumbnail('large');
} else {
    the_post_thumbnail('medium');
}
```

You can create additional image sizes specifically for your homepage by adding this in functions.php:

```
add_image_size( 'homepage-large', 620, 620);
```

Answer (score -1):

A featured image is saved as an attachment ID, you can use the `get_post_thumbnail` function as a shortcut to grabbing other sizes like this:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'the first image size');
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'the other image size');
```

Comment: How does this help me?  I need to have two different featured image sizes on the homepage not 1 size...

Comment: Because now you know how to show the featured image at any arbitrary size, you can simply do it twice specifying a different image each time

Comment: If you would like two different images at different size, rather than the featured image at 2 sizes ( not the same thing ) please modify your question and I will ammend my answer

Answer (score -1):

Look in the functions.php of the theme you are using and you can easily change:

```
// Enable post thumbnails
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size(620, 200, true);
```

I also used another function on one of my sites

```
$i = 0
foreach(...){
  if($i == 0){
     echo '<img width="400" src="...">';
  }else{
     echo '<img width="200" src="...">';
  $i++
}
```

Comment: Could you explain bit more what this does?  I really don't understand.  I need two different featured images sizes for the homepage.